# NLog - Invalid xsi:type 'http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd:AzureAppendBlob'

Tags: c#, nlog

I'm trying to use **NLog.AzureAppendBlob** package to append the blob in Azure.

To achieve this, I have added a nuget package **NLog.AzureAppendBlob** and also have updated **Nlog.config** to add extension as below ***before defining the target***.

```xml
<extensions>
  <add assembly="NLog.AzureAppendBlob" />
</extensions>
```

Below is the reason. It is not able to find the xsi:type for Nlog.AzureAppendLog.

[image: Error occurring at this location]

Pls let me kow if I'm missing anything in here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some analysis I found that the issue is the NLog version **NLog.AzureAppendBlob** is using.

I have removed that package and used [NLog.Extensions.AzureStorage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Extensions.AzureStorage) and it started working fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is a warning you could ignore.

In the XSD all official targets are listed. Because NLog.AzureAppendBlob is a 3rd party component, this will result in a warning.

This won't influence the behavior of NLog

Comment: Actually I am unable to ignore the warning as when I try to build the project, it is throwing the error I have mentioned in the title of the question.

Comment: if you close the file in VS, then you should not get that warning.

Comment: No, it was not warning and an error while building the solution.